# Persistencia de datos en Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Buenas estimados, estoy creando una app donde en la primera activity hago un filtro de regiones del país y luego los paso por putextra a la siguiente actividad donde llamo un webservice con el respectivo filtro para que me traiga los datos correctos, posterior a eso al hacer click en la lista filtrada se abre otra actividad con el detalle del item clickeado, pero al volver a la lista me dice que el putextra viene vacío, se pierden los datos que venían del filtro de la primera actividad, espero ser claro.

Primer activity, mando el filtro

```
if (position == 0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Turismo.this,Contrato.class);
                intent.putExtra("region",spinnerRegion.getSelectedItemPosition());
                intent.putExtra("grilla",position);
                startActivity(intent);
```

En la segunda lo recibo y posteriormente llamo el web service, hasta ahi todo bien. lleno un recyclerview para la vista.

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();
    datoregion = (String)extra.get("region").toString();
    String datgrilla = (String)extra.get("grilla").toString();
```

en la tercera actividad muestro el detalle que trae el web service.

```
nombre.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("nombre"));
    descripcion.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("descripcion"));
    Picasso.with(context).load(getIntent().getStringExtra("imagen_public")).into(imageView);
```

al volver de la tercera actividad me aparece el error

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.os.Bundle.get(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

He averiguado sobre sharepreferences pero nose donde colocarlo.
De ante mano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Guarda los valores del bundle por medio del método [onSaveInstanceState()](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) :

```
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
      // El bundle sera guardado y enviado al onCreate() de la Activity.
      savedInstanceState.putString("region", valorRegion);
      savedInstanceState.putString("grilla", valorGrilla);
    }
```

De esta forma los podras obtener nuevamente en la actividad, por medio de onRestoreInstanceState(), puedes recuperar los valores:

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.

  String valorRegion = savedInstanceState.getString("region");

String valorGrilla = savedInstanceState.getString("grilla");

}
```

Comment: los logro guardar en onSaveInstanceState pero al volver me quedo null nuevamente :(

Comment: Valida si el bundle es nulo no obtenga valores, los valores los puedes obtener en onRestoreInstanceState()

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar sharedPreferences para almacenar los datos:

```
//de esta manera obtienes los datos del SharedPreferences.
SharedPreferences datos = getSharedPreferences("datos", 0);
String datoregion = datos.getString("region","null");
String datgrilla = datos.getString("grilla","null");

//de esta manera insertas los datos
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = datos.edit();
editor.putString("region", valorRegion);
editor.putString("grilla", valorGrilla);
editor.commit();
```

El sharedpreferences seria como un documento de texto que se encarga de mantener datos en la memoria del teléfono.